# IndexedDB выборка результатов

Tags: javascript, sql, веб-программирование, indexeddb

Если у меня в таблице есть поле age с разными и повторяющимися значениями от 1 до 100 как сделать выборку строк со значениями age от 18 до 25.

Comment: Тривиальный вопрос.  select * from table1 where age between  18 and 25

Comment: Ну это ведь sql, там по моему все по другому устроено